# Camera Space OpenGL Tutorial

Tags: opengl, perspectivecamera

I'm following the tutorial at http://alfonse.bitbucket.org/oldtut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html which I believe the user, Nicol Bolas, is the author. Under the Camera Perspective topic, I am getting stuck.

"Our perspective projection transform will be specific to this space. As previously stated, the projection plane shall be a region [-1, 1] in the X and Y axes, and at a Z value of -1. The projection will be from vertices in the -Z direction onto this plane; vertices that have a positive Z value are behind the projection plane.

Now, we will make one more simplifying assumption: the location of the center of the perspective plane is fixed at (0, 0, -1) in camera space. Therefore, since the projection plane is pointing down the -Z axis, eye's location relative to the plane of projection is (0, 0, -1). Thus, the Ez value, the offset from the projection plane to the eye, is always -1. This means that our perspective term, when phrased as division rather than multiplication, is simply Pz/-1: the negation of the camera-space Z coordinate."

Isn't the eye's location relative to the plane of projection a positive 1 in the z direction?

My understanding is the eye is at (0,0,0) and the plane's center is at (0,0,-1). Relatively, the eye is +1 in the z direction to the plane.

I was doing really well understanding this tutorial with this exception. I can even look past it and understand the rest of the tutorial while just believing this, but that's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Therefore, since the projection plane is pointing down the -Z axis, eye's location relative to the plane of projection is (0, 0, -1).

It's probably best to pretend that this sentence doesn't exist. In fact, *it doesn't exist.* I defy you to prove me wrong.

No fair [looking at the Bitbucket repo either](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/commits/all) ;)

Comment: First off, I am glad to see you back on these boards. I saw you started posting again last month. Your answers on here have helped me tremendously and so has your tutorial. I noticed your absence for 2 years and I'm sure many others have, too. So the above highlighted statement means the projection plane is pointing down the -Z axis towards the eye or away from the eye? +Z E(0,0,0) P(0,0,-1) -Z is how I see the description which would mean the eye is (0,0,1) relative from the plane. I'm sorry if I'm not making it clear of how I am seeing things.

Comment: You're not understanding what I said. Forget everything that the paragraph said before. Now re-read the entire paragraph *without that sentence*. I even removed it from the website. It shouldn't have been there. It doesn't matter what the eye's position is relative to the plane of projection.

Comment: Okay, I did read it again and yes it does help a lot without that sentence. I was reading it from a downloaded copy that includes all the source code, sorry. Thanks and I hope to see you provide more guidance on here in the future.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whatever happened to arcsynthesis? Did a domain squatter kill it? It's great to see the content is still available, but a massive collection of questions and answers on Stack Overflow link to something that no longer exists, and it's an impossible chore going back and fixing them.